# Unable to cast object of type NullableData[ExDateTime]' to type 'DateTimeData' when calling Me.MailFolders[id].Messages.Delta

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

Two days ago we started getting the following error when using the Microsoft Graph SDK and calling `GraphServiceClient.Me.MailFolders[id].Messages.Delta()` for one of our customers:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.NullableData`2[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.DateTimeData,Microsoft.Exchange.ExchangeSystem.ExDateTime]' to type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.DateTimeData'.

Initially we thought this was something wrong with this particular client's email folder, but yesterday and today the error started showing up with other customers as well.

The code using the endpoint has been unchanged for more than a year, and we're unable to reproduce the error with any of our accounts or in the Graph Explorer.

We've updated to the latest version of the `Microsoft.Graph` and `Microsoft.Graph.Core` packages (4.34.0 and 2.0.9 respectively) and the problem remains there.

Comment: Looks like a server side error and I'm afraid it's not clear how to report this kind of error directly to Graph API dev team @darrelmiller